# Checking whether a Japan reservation site is legit

Tags: japan, tokyo

I'm trying to reserve for a restaurant in Tokyo that got stellar reviews (Ginza Kyubey). As such I need to reserve a long time in advance. The one site I found online that takes reservation and is in English is [JPNEAZY](https://jpneazy.com/).

I don't seem able to find reputable information on whether this site is safe and it requires payment upfront.

How does one go about checking whether this is safe and legit?

Comment: I'm trying to use it as well but it is asking me to pay the full amount for the lunch ahead. Did you had to pay as well?
Also, I called the restaurant, their English was very poor and they told me no space on the day I have my booking

Comment: Yeah, did that, felt risky, but apparently normal for Japan. Agreed too on poor English. That said, the chef and staff were super friendly although we could only communicate with gestures and few words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jpneazy is not a reservation site, but a "cloud concierge" site (their wording): there's a human in the middle making reservations, and you need to pay them for the privilege.  So while I can't comment on whether it's safe or legit, there's definitely an extra layer in the middle adding to the cost.

The official Kyubey site (https://www.kyubey.jp) site appears to be down as I type this, but it looks like they outsource their reservations to Ikyu at https://restaurant.ikyu.com/107953/.  The site is Japanese only, but should be navigable through Google Translate or equivalent.  Beware that reservations via Ikyu are on a "request" basis and not guaranteed until confirmed by the restaurant.

Comment: As it turns out, the site was legit and the reservation was correctly arranged.